# Specify path in vbs script

Tags: vbscript, path

I've searched all over, but couldnt find any answer. I want the savetofile path to be at the desktop, regardless of username. but i get an error. I think it is about the path, that causes the error. Any tips?

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://banos.me/Despacito.mp3", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile ""C:\Users\"" & LoginName & ""\Desktop\"", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

Comment: The error message would be great ...

Comment: You should not put twice the double quotes on the .savetofile line... and you should not put despacito.mp3 on any desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have not specified how you get *LoginName*.
This code works:

```
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
Dim objShell
Dim userPath

Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
userPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
filePath = userPath &"\Despacito.mp3"

xHttp.Open "GET", "http://banos.me/Despacito.mp3", False
xHttp.Send
filePath = userPath &"\Despacito.mp3"

with bStrm
    .type = 1
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile filePath, 2
end with
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yo're welcome! Take a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156616.aspx for more info about Special Folders.